# How to add driver to bootable USB

Tags: windows-7, boot, format, bootable-media, slipstream

I want to install Windows 7 on my Lenovo ThinkPad T460p and I did, but the problem is USB ports and/or network adapters not working and that's why I can't install my drivers. How can I create a bootable disk and add my drivers to this bootable disk? Is there any way to install my drivers to inside of this bootable USB, and when I start my laptop after Windows 7 installation is finished, I want to directly install my drivers?

Comment: I assume you are trying to slipstream a USB 3.0 driver into your Windows 7 ISO.  What have you tried?  There are numerous articles on how to do this, what step are you stuck on exactly, because your also asking how to create the bootable media itself.

Comment: [Installing Microsoft Windows* 7 from USB Drives onto USB 3.0 Computers](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/25476/eng/win7-usb3.0-creator-readme-v3.pdf)

Comment: the problem is, i formated my laptop and installed windows 7 and no usb port and network adapter working, they are on device manager but they need a driver to work. i asked that is there any way to install my drivers to inside of this bootable usb and when i start my laptop after windows 7 installation, i want to drirectly install my drivers. Sorry for my english.

Comment: You cannot install Windows 7 on a device if it only has USB 3 ports unless you slipstream the required drivers.  Normally you would be asked for the driver when you installed it, in this case, the driver is actually required before the installation even begins.  There is *NO* way around this requirement.

Comment: How did you install Windows 7 if you have no working USB ports?